# How to track file nested in untracked folder?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

Our current git setup works on a whitelist basis, so everything is ignored by default, and we then include directories as needed. This worked fine for a new repository, but is starting to cause issues now that we have a bunch of tracked/untracked files.

Here's an example of our .gitignore:

```
*
!/example.txt
!/example2.txt
```

I'm now trying to add a file to git that exists in ignored folder `a`, the file's path is: `/a/b/c/file.txt`. My question is, how can I go about not ignoring this file, but ignoring everything else in the /a folder?

So far I've found that adding this to the .gitignore works:

```
!/a/
!/a/b/
!/a/b/c/
!/a/b/c/file.txt
```

However, it just seems a bit messy. I originally thought that I'd be able to get away with just having `!/a/b/c/file.txt` in the .gitignore, but that doesn't seem to work for some reason?

Also for reference, I'm having to run `git rm --cached -r .` and `git add .` to get .gitignore changes to take effect.

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add `!*/`. This whitelists directories. Here is a sample ignore..

```
# ignore everything
*
# don't ignore directories
!*/
# whitelist files with extension
*.xyz

# blacklist individual file
a/b/c.xyz
```

Other options is to blacklist everything in the directory and whitelist the one file

```
a/b/c/*
!a/b/c/file.txt
```

Comment: The `!*/` rule *will* work, but it also defeats the speed hack that ignoring a directory gains. That may well be worth the tradeoff: it's up to whoever is writing the `.gitignore` to decide, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

[`git add --force`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--f) can be used to add ignored files:

```
git add -f a/b/c/file.txt
```

After being added the file is tracked and no longer ignored.

Comment: Seems like that could work, but we like being able to use .gitignore as a source of what should/shouldn't be in the repo.